# Insert into another table issue

Tags: php, sql

I want this code to execute when the user clicks the button "submit my question".  Where I should put this in my php file?  In the head tags, perhaps?

Can you also tell me if this code is wrong?

```
INSERT INTO sales_order_holder [(pid, brand, ... columnN)] 
SELECT pid, brand, ...columnN 
FROM products
[WHERE selected row's id]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sperate my php code into an other file, to first make it cleaner and easier to maintain. Second on your html file, the form that's being submitted (i presume this is the case) make sure in your action attribute you add your php file. Like so 
`<form action="myfile.php" method="post">`
 and inside your form you can add your input type of submit to submit your form. The form will then execute the script in the "myfile.php" file. Which should contain your query.

Comment: do you think my query is right ? . i can't do your advice because my form action where my submit button is already used. so i will put my query where the form action do. but anyway thankyou for response. i appreciate it.